Alternative to Merge by Distance node for constructing an arbitrary mesh in geometry nodes?
I am looking at the four answers given to How to subdivide triangles into four triangles with Geometry Nodes?
In every one of the six solutions proposed in these four answers,
the sore spot (in both performance and quality of output) is the final "Merge by Distance" node.
This single node is always the strong bottleneck of the entire thing (50% to 90% of the time taken).
And it's not robust-- it can change/wreck the structure of the mesh, depending on proximity of unrelated vertices to each other.
All the algorithms implemented in these solutions are really O(n) and should not require any O(n log n) tools at all, let alone this big dull instrument that is the Merge by Distance node.
My general simple question is: is there any better way to piece together an arbitrary mesh in geometry nodes?
Using zones (Repeat or For Each Element) is fine, without them would be even better.
Maybe just show an example of how to create a cube (without using the Cube node) or tetrahedron, without using Merge By Distance, if it's possible.

Could you detail what is the starting geometry ? A single face that is subdivided ? A point cloud ? A set of unconnected, but adjacent, faces ? e.g. for the cube case, do you start with 8 vertices, or 4 faces, or a single vertex ?

Unfortunately, this is basically a computationally complex matter. Points have to be found and moved, edges removed, attributes created/interpolated, etc.. I am currently not aware of any other method and unfortunately there is no "Merge by Group" node or similar.

@quellenform - I think you have put your finger on it-- a "Merge by Group" node would solve this perfectly in most cases I'm thinking of.  In particular, would solve the problem in every one of the four solutions in the question I linked, making them all robust and much faster.   (Calculating the group IDs would be straightforward in every case, though it may take many steps.)

@StefLAncien To start, I'd like to see how to create a cube or tetrahedron, from nothing; if I knew how to do that, it would probably reveal the general method to do everything else. Other example inputs are: any of the inputs to the Merge by Distance node in any of the 6 answers to the question I linked: that is, a triangle mesh whose triangles are separated and we want to merge coincident vertices (where "coincident" means "has the same value of some input integer field"). Or, say, a point cloud and a list of triangles (triples of indices into that point cloud).

What you can do is extrude vertices, move them to separate spots (group spots), merge them, then you can move them to original places and do merge by distance in "connected" mode. This way you can control exactly what merges with what.

@MarkusvonBroady This sounds promising, but I'm lost.  What situation are you describing a solution for? (Is this a recipe for emulating "Merge By Group ID"?)

@DonHatch yes, you can have full control what you merge by using this technique.

@MarkusvonBroady Ok great. It's not clear to me yet whether this will solve the performance problem or just the low-quality-output problem, but maybe that will become clear as soon as I understand what you're saying.  I'm still not following what you're describing at all. (Extrude which vertices? Move which of the resulting vertices?  Then "Merge them" how? The only node I see that merges vertices is "Merge by Distance", so that sounds like you're saying do two "Merge by Distance"s? Clearly I'm misinterpreting some or several steps of what you're saying, but I'm really completely lost here.)

@MarkusvonBroady your description makes me think of this, though. No vertex extrusion here, but I think this is a robust (although still slow) implementation of Merge by Group ID: save positions, set positions to Group ID (converting int to vector), Merge by Distance, restore positions. https://i.sstatic.net/wiUh7OzY.png Details: I expected distance=0 to work inside, but it doesn't for some reason (unexpected internal roundoff error?) But distance=0.5 works. And this can be improved to handle full range of 64-bit ints by mapping i=>(i//2**44, i//2**22%2**22, i%2**22) instead of i=>(i,i,i).

Hmm that's annoying, it looks to me like the kd-tree deduping implementation is just broken for small distances (in particular 0). This looks really easy to fix; just change the <= to < on this line and the >= to > five lines below that.

I filed a bug report on the distance=0 misbehavior.

(Oh, regarding my comment above about handling all 64-bit ints-- I see now that Integer is only 32 bits in geometry nodes anyway.  So, the best we can do is handle all 32-bit ints, by some similar manipulation involving the Combine XYZ node.)

The way I would handle this problem is documenting that above 2²⁴ The groups start to merge due to float32 innaccuracy. BTW I mentioned extrusion because I somehow thought sometimes you maybe would want 1 vertex to end up in multiple places, but I didn't think this through so possibly the extrusion part doesn't make sense.
